# Windows docker-machine adding ssh.exe to PATH

Tags: python, windows, cmd

According to the docker-machine documentation for installation on Windows, I need to run the following command to add `ssh.exe` to the `%PATH%` environment variable:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

This is so that `cmd.exe` can recognize `docker-machine` as a command. However, running the above command just doesn't seem to do anything at all. The same thing happens when I try this in Powershell:

```
$Env:Path = "${Env:Path};c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

which is to say, apparently nothing at all. My goal is to make `docker-machine` a recognizable command in `cmd.exe`. This is because I have a Python script to set up the `docker-machine` VM and the script needs to be able to run in `cmd.exe`. How exactly can this be done? It's important to not go into Advanced System Settings from My Computer and modify environment variables that way, since that requires admin privileges and the setup needs to work without any sort of admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's important to not go into Advanced System Settings from My
>   Computer and modify environment variables that way, since that
>   requires admin privileges and the setup needs to work without any sort
>   of admin privileges.

A non-admin user can set environment variables that only affect their profile (as opposed to the entire machine).  See this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/25038) for how to access the **Environment Variables** dialog directly without having to go through the **Advanced System Settings** dialog.

From here, you can set `PATH` in the *User variables* list.  Note that, when using this method, you don't need to include the existing path (i.e. `%PATH%`) as you did above.  The value you enter in the *User variables* list will be appended to the current system value for `PATH`.

Also, don't forget that after setting an environment variable using this method, existing `cmd` instances will **not** see the new value for `PATH` -- you must open a new `cmd` instance.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that. I can see that the correct env variable was added to PATH doing what you said, yet `cmd` still doesn't recognize `docker-machine` even when I open a new `cmd` instance.

Comment: Dumb question, but did you verify the directory you're adding to `PATH` actually includes `docker-machine.exe` (or `docker-machine.bat`)?

Comment: I don't think it's a dumb question considering how little I know about doing this kind of work in Windows. Turns out it's not there at all. Weird, considering I correctly installed Docker Toolbox for Windows like I was supposed to

Comment: I'm not a Docker user, so this statement may be wrong, but it [appears](https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/) Docker for Windows requires the use of a MinGW bash shell (the so-called Docker CLI).  That means you will **not** be able to run `docker-machine` (note: no extension) from `cmd`.  However, you should be able to run your Python script from the Docker CLI.

Comment: Then I think it is better to use that shell so I'll move forward with that. Still, it gives me the same error as before, not recognizing `docker-machine`. But thanks for pointing out that shell, it's definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the current documentation says to use `cmd.exe`; the link you posted is for an older version of Docker. In any case, I still can't fix this error.

Comment: Sorry... yes, you're right.  The correct docs are [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/).  I think the confusion may be that the installation instructions are specifying that **ssh.exe** is in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` folder (which is what I'm assuming you're adding to `PATH`), not **docker-machine.exe**.  You need to ensure `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox` is also in `PATH` (although, the docs suggest that happens as part of the Toolbox installation).

Comment: How funny, I just found out the same thing before even seeing you commented this and just posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the original `set` command is necessary, but it is definitely not the whole story. I found out after a lot of digging around that you need to make sure that Docker Toolbox is also in your `PATH` variable. The following needs to be added:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
```

I don't know why the Docker documentation neglects to mention this. Maybe it's assumed that it will automatically make it there after installation. In my case, that is not what happened and I had to manually ensure that Docker Toolbox was in `PATH`.

Thanks to Rusty Shackleford for helping me find the environment variables without using admin privileges.

Comment: Did you reboot or log off and back on again?

Comment: I did, though I encountered these issues before any of that happened. I think for me, Docker Toolbox somehow never ended up in my `PATH` since I had these troubles from the start.

Comment: Why do you say the install can't require admin privileges? Installing into `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` already requires admin privileges.

Comment: Good point...I DID have to ask a supervisor of mine to install Docker Toolbox on the Windows RDP after all. He then later said that further steps should not require admin privileges but the fact that Docker Toolbox itself needs it already makes the Windows setup script a little pointless, since it's still true that setup should not require admin. It would be a hassle for someone to manually install Toolbox for every Windows setup.

Comment: The installer should have added the `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox` directory to the system `PATH`. You can verify that from the command prompt with the following command: `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH`. However, given an administrator did the install, maybe it only modified it for that user instead of for the system.

Comment: That seems most plausible, since everything else seemed to indicate a normal Docker Toolbox install.